# How to use Thrift Scala classes generated by Scrooge?

Tags: scala, sbt, thrift, scrooge

I'm new to Thrift and only recently have learned how to write basic thrift services and implement client/server in Java and Python.

I want to use Thrift in Scala and didn't want to use Java like syntax. So came across Scrooge.

What exactly is the difference between the classes generated by Scrooge and that generated by Thrift and how can I use Scrooge generated classes in Scala?

Can I use Scrooge to generate classes for Scala and same thrift files to generate code for Python using thrift generator?

How do I generate code with Thrift? I've heard of an SBT plugin, not sure if I understand well enough how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you follow the Scrooge documentation? Do you have specific problems?

The Scrooge-generated classes are (hopefully) more idiomatic for use in scala.  You use them by... using them, like any other class (bear in mind scrooge server-side scala classes use Finagle - if your application is not Finagle-ey you might find them less convenient than the java ones). You can indeed use Scrooge to generate classes for Scala and thrift to generate them for Python. You probably want to use the Scrooge plugin for maven or SBT (whichever you use for building your project) to generate the classes - both are explained on the scrooge website.

Comment: "The Scrooge-generated classes are (hopefully) more idiomatic for use in scala."
How is it different from Java API? What's the API provided? That's what I wanna know.

Comment: It's things like scala style property access rather than JavaBean get/set. Honestly just run it and look at the generated code is going to be much easier than trying to describe the differences.